# splunk search query returns entries with a variable value greater than some number

Tags: splunk

I've this log entry:

---

"2014-11-22 02:42:10,545 .. - average:2.74425 , min:1.43 , max:4.007..."

---

i want to create a search query that returns all log entries with "average > 5"

i want to select the date of the log entry and the average value,

can this be done? how can i do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple to do in Splunk and you'll have to do it in two steps:

1. Parse your log to get each of the fields in your log files. To do this use the [props.conf](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.2.0/admin/Propsconf) and [transforms.conf](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.2.0/Admin/Transformsconf) files on your indexer server or on your client if you are using the heavy forwarder. Another option is to send you fields using the key=value format that Splunk knows how to parse by default. Example: "2014-11-22 02:42:10,545 .. - average=2.74425 min=1.43 max=4.007..."
2. After getting your fields in Splunk just search for average>5 and you'll get all these search results easily.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from splunk:

Did you already extract the average field?

If not, go to Settings -> Fields -> Field Extractions -> New, enter "average" as name, fill in your sourcetype, and use this as inline extraction:

```
average:(?<average>\d+\.?\d*)
```

it worked. :)